# How can I make `await …` work with `yield return` (i.e. inside an iterator method)?

Tags: c#, ado.net, async-await, generator, yield-return

I have existing code that looks similar to:

```
IEnumerable<SomeClass> GetStuff()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            SomeClass someClass = f(reader); // create instance based on returned row
            yield return someClass;
        }
    } 
}
```

It seems I could benefit by using `reader.ReadAsync()`. However, if I just modify the one line:

```
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
```

the compiler informs me that `await` can only be used in methods marked with `async`, and suggests I modify the method signature to be:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<SomeClass>> GetStuff()
```

However, doing that makes `GetStuff()` unusable because:

> *The body of `GetStuff()` cannot be an iterator block because `Task<IEnumerable<SomeClass>>` is not an iterator interface type.*

I'm sure I am missing a key concept with the async programming model.

**Questions:**

- Can I use `ReadAsync()` in my iterator? How?
- How can I think about the async paradigm differently so that I understand how it works in this type of situation?

Comment: Is the iterator block actually useful here? Wouldn't building `List<SomClass>` and returning that work almost the same?

Comment: @svick: No, because processing SomeClass is expensive.  Results of the iterator block are processed by multiple threads.  Building the full list would take many minutes against the production data which is time that could be spent processing the result.  Also, the full list would be quite large, consuming memory needlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of C# 8, this can be accomplished with [IAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8)

Modified code:

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<SomeClass> GetStuff()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            SomeClass someClass = f(reader); // create instance based on returned row
            yield return someClass;
        }
    } 
}
```

Consume it like this:

```
await foreach (var stuff in GetStuff())
    ...
```

Answer (score 22):

The problem is what you're asking doesn't actually make much sense. `IEnumerable<T>` is a synchronous interface, and returning `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` isn't going to help you much, because some thread would have to block waiting for each item, no matter what.

What you actually want to return is some asynchronous alternative to `IEnumerable<T>`: something like `IObservable<T>`, dataflow block from TPL Dataflow or `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, which is planned to be added to C# 8.0/.Net Core 3.0. (And in the meantime, there are [some](http://asyncenum.codeplex.com/) [libraries](https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable) that contain it.)

Using TPL Dataflow, one way to do this would be:

```
ISourceBlock<SomeClass> GetStuff() {
    var block = new BufferBlock<SomeClass>();

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                SomeClass someClass;
                // Create an instance of SomeClass based on row returned.
                block.Post(someClass);
            }
            block.Complete();
        } 
    });

    return block;
}
```

You'll probably want to add error handling to the above code, but otherwise, it should work and it will be completely asynchronous.

The rest of your code would then consume items from the returned block also asynchronously, probably using `ActionBlock`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but for readers: Mike's Answer is better, look below!

Comment: @CsabaToth Could you explain why do you think so? And Mike included two alternatives in his answer, which one did you mean? (Also, I tend to downvote answers that are actually wrong or promote bad practices, not just if I think another answer is better. But of course it's up to you how you vote.)

Comment: Naively, having only just started looking at TPL Dataflow, this looks like a much nicer solution, as it's one of the kinds of problem that I gather Dataflow is intended to solve (and relatively optimally).

Comment: Svick , does the ExecuteReaderAsync() fetches ALL the relevant rows from db ? Or is it the ReadAsync who does it  ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir If `ExecuteReaderAsync()` retrieved all rows, then there would be no reason to make `ReadAsync()` asynchronous. But that's just my guess, on a quick glance the documentation doesn't say anything about it and I don't know how is it actually implemented.

Comment: Why am I asking ? because , like you said , the DOCS says nothing about it and the other guy here said   soemthing which made me wonder : http://i.imgur.com/dhLF9g4.png

Comment: Also , look at this ,  it seems that it fetches bulks at first place , and then when the network card buffer is full , it fetches again : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6035078/859154 , so `ExecuteReaderAsync` _fetches all he can_ ,  where in that case -the `async` in  `ReadAsync` _is_ redaunant.... (again  , I dont know , that's why I asked you).

Comment: @svick, is there a way of doing this that doesn't consume a thread from the threadpool? Or should that be a new question?

Comment: @MarcL. My example code doesn't consume a thread while it's waiting for data from the SQL server, that's how `await` works.

Answer (score 20):

No, you can't currently use async with an iterator block. As svick says, you would need something like `IAsyncEnumerable` to do that.

If you have the return value `Task<IEnumerable<SomeClass>>` it means that the function returns a single `Task` object that, once completed, will provide you with a fully formed IEnumerable (no room for Task asynchrony in this enumerable). Once the task object is complete, the caller should be able to synchronously iterate through all the items it returned in the enumerable.

Here is a solution that returns `Task<IEnumerable<SomeClass>>`. You could get a large part of benefit of async by doing something like this:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<SomeClass>> GetStuff()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            return ReadItems(reader).ToArray();
        }
    }
}

IEnumerable<SomeClass> ReadItems(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Create an instance of SomeClass based on row returned.
        SomeClass someClass = null;
        yield return someClass;
    }
}
```

...and an example usage:

```
async void Caller()
{
    // Calls get-stuff, which returns immediately with a Task
    Task<IEnumerable<SomeClass>> itemsAsync = GetStuff();
    // Wait for the task to complete so we can get the items
    IEnumerable<SomeClass> items = await itemsAsync;
    // Iterate synchronously through the items which are all already present
    foreach (SomeClass item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Here you have the iterator part and the async part in separate functions which allows you to use both the async and yield syntax. The `GetStuff` function asynchronously acquires the data, and the `ReadItems` then synchronously reads the data into an enumerable.

Note the `ToArray()` call. Something like this is necessary because the enumerator function executes lazily and so your async function may otherwise dispose the connection and command before all the data is read. This is because the `using` blocks cover the duration of the `Task` execution, but you would be iterating it `after` the task is complete.

This solution does *not* use `ReadAsync`, but it *does* use `OpenAsync` and `ExecuteReaderAsync`, which probably gives you most of the benefit. In my experience it is the ExecuteReader that will take the most time and have the most benefit being async. By the time I've read the first row, the `SqlDataReader` has all the other rows already and `ReadAsync` just returns synchronously. If this is the case for you as well then you won't get significant benefit by moving to a push-based system like `IObservable<T>` (which will require significant modifications to the calling function).

For illustration, consider an alternative approach to the same issue:

```
IEnumerable<Task<SomeClass>> GetStuff()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (true)
                yield return ReadItem(reader);
        }
    }
}

async Task<SomeClass> ReadItem(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    if (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        // Create an instance of SomeClass based on row returned.
        SomeClass someClass = null;
        return someClass;
    }
    else
        return null; // Mark end of sequence
}
```

...and an example usage:

```
async void Caller()
{
    // Synchronously get a list of Tasks
    IEnumerable<Task<SomeClass>> items = GetStuff();
    // Iterate through the Tasks
    foreach (Task<SomeClass> itemAsync in items)
    {
        // Wait for the task to complete. We need to wait for 
        // it to complete before we can know if it's the end of
        // the sequence
        SomeClass item = await itemAsync;
        // End of sequence?
        if (item == null) 
            break;
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

In this case, `GetStuff` returns immediately with an enumerable, where each item in the enumerable is a task that will present a `SomeClass` object when it completes. This approach has a few flaws. Firstly, the enumerable returns synchronously so at the time it returns we actually don't know how many rows are in the result, which is why I made it an infinite sequence. This is perfectly legal but it has some side effects. I needed to use `null` to signal the end of useful data in the infinite sequence of tasks. Secondly, you have to be careful about how you iterate it. You need to iterate it forwards, and you need to wait for each row before iterating to the next row. You must also only dispose of the iterator after all the tasks have completed so that the GC doesn't collect connection before it's finished being used. For these reasons this is not a safe solution, and I must emphasize that I'm including it for illustration to help answer your second question.

Comment: I believe you're wrong that `SqlConnection.Dispose()` won't be called in your second version. The connection is in a `using` in the iterator block method, so it will be disposed when the enumerator is disposed, which happens at the end of `foreach` automatically. And you could use similar approach in your first version by passing the disposable objects to `ReadItems()`.

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct. I've removed that statement from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking strictly to async iterator's (or there possibility) within the context of a `SqlCommand` in my experience I've noticed that the synchronous version of the code vastly outperforms it's `async` counterpart. In both speed and memory consumption.

> Perhaps, take this observation with a grain of salt as the scope of the testing was limited to my machine and local SQL Server instance.

Don't get me wrong, the [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx) paradigm within the .NET environment is phenomenally simple, powerful and useful given the right circumstances. After much toiling however, I'm not convinced database access is a proper use case for it. Unless of course you're needing to execute several commands simultaneously, in which case you can simply use [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) to fire off the commands in unison.

My preferred approach rather is to take the following considerations:

- Keep the units of *SQL work* small, simple and compose-able (i.e. make your SQL executions "cheap").
- Avoid doing work on the SQL Server that can be push upstream to the app-level. A perfect example of this is sorting.
- Most importantly, test your SQL code at scale and review Statistics IO output/execution plan. A query which runs quickly at 10k record, may (and probably will) behave entirely differently when there a 1M records.

You could make the argument that in certain reporting scenarios, some of the above requirements just aren't possible. However, in the context of reporting services is asynchronous-ity (is that even a word?) really needed?

There's a fantastic [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2009/11/14/should-my-database-calls-be-asynchronous/) by Microsoft evangelist Rick Anderson about this very topic. Mind you it's old (from 2009) but still very relevant.