# Using async / await with DataReader ? ( without middle buffers!)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, io, async-await, .net-4.5

My goal is simple , I want to do Asynchronous I/O calls (using async await)  - but :

- Without using DataFlow dependency ( [*like in this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13148683/859154))
- Without middle buffers( [*not like this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13148683/859154))
- The Projector function should be sent as an argument. ( [*not like this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13149492/859154))

Ok.

Currently here is my code which it's job is to read from db and project each line to a `Func<>`

```
public IEnumerable < T > GetSomeData < T > (string sql, Func < IDataRecord, T > projector)
{
    using(SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=..."))
    {
        using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _conn))
        {
            _conn.Open();
            _cmd.CommandTimeout = 100000;
            using(IDataReader rdr = _cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())  yield    return projector(rdr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So  , what is projector ?

Each class has a function which gets a `record` ( `IDataRecord`) and create an entity :

Example :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass MyClassFactory(IDataRecord record)
    {
        return new MyClass
        {
            Name = record["Name"].ToString(),
            Datee = DateTime.Parse(record["Datee"].ToString()),
            val = decimal.Parse(record["val"].ToString())
        };
    }
    public string Name    {   get;   set;  }
    public DateTime Datee    {  get;     set;  }
    public decimal val    {  get;    set;    }
}
```

So here ,  `MyClassFactory` would be the `Func`

So how I currently run it ?

```
 var sql = @"SELECT TOP 1000 [NAME],[datee] ,[val]  FROM [WebERP].[dbo].[t]";
 var a = GetSomeData < MyClass > (sql, MyClass.MyClassFactory).Where(...); //notice the Func
```

**All ok.**

The problems starts now :

Adding `async` to the method  yields an error : ( Yes I know that Ienumerable is a *Synchronous* interface hence the problem)

`public async Task<IEnumerable < T >> GetSomeData < T > (string sql, Func < IDataRecord, T > projector)`

> cannot be an iterator block because
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
>   is not an iterator interface type

[*But this guy here did*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13149492/859154) -  :

[image]

Which **DOES** compile.

**Question**

How can I convert **my code** to support fully asynchronse IO call ?

*(under the conditions : without DataFlow dependency , send projector function as argument , no middle buffers)*

Comment: For such cases it would be nice if C# supported `IAsyncEnumerator`. If you are OK with returning an eagerly filled list in a fully async way the question becomes much easier.

Comment: `ToArray` does create a middle buffer.

Comment: Your code iterates.  The code that compiles does not.  IEnumerable is not the problem.  Iterating (ie: `yield return`) is the problem.  What's the problem with a buffer?

Comment: How about http://asyncenum.codeplex.com

Comment: * (please don't make me switch to NODEJS) :-) hahaha

Comment: @I3arnon Yes but as you can see , it's not my code :-) .  indeed ToArray is a buffer. I'd hate to put the result in a buffer , and then iterate over it again. isn't it possible to iterate it via one  time ?

Comment: @usr is there any possible solution of which I don't have to create middle buffer ?  I mean  , Does the only solution is to create middle buffer ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir you'd have to expose to the caller per-element asynchronicity. IEnumerable cannot do that. Taking an element is always synchronous. You need to use an async model like IAsyncEnumerator. There seem to be reasonable libraries around that idea (https://asyncenum.codeplex.com/). Nothing built-in. Also, the performance hit taken for buffering is so little compared to all the ADO.NET and SQL work that avoiding buffering does not have any meaningful effect of throughput. Would still make sense for streaming huge data sets.

Comment: @usr: I believe `Ix-Async` still has an async enumerator.

Comment: Have you considered using Rx or TPL Dataflow?

Comment: You can also do this with Rx - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24968048/1239433

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I want to do Asynchronous I/O calls (using async await) - but :
>
> - Without using DataFlow dependency ( like in this answer)
> - Without middle buffers( not like this answer)
> - The Projector function should be sent as an argument. ( not like this answer)

You may want to check Stephen Toub's ["Tasks, Monads, and LINQ"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/04/03/tasks-monads-and-linq.aspx) for some great ideas on how to process asynchronous data sequences.

It's not (yet) possible to combine `yield` and `await`, but I'm going to be a verbalist here: the quoted requirements didn't list `IEnumerable` and LINQ. So, here's a possible solution shaped as two coroutines (almost untested).

Data producer routine (corresponds to `IEnumarable` with `yield`):

```
public async Task GetSomeDataAsync<T>(
    string sql, Func<IDataRecord, T> projector, ProducerConsumerHub<T> hub)
{
    using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=..."))
    {
        using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _conn))
        {
            await _conn.OpenAsync();
            _cmd.CommandTimeout = 100000;
            using (var rdr = await _cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await rdr.ReadAsync())
                    await hub.ProduceAsync(projector(rdr));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data consumer routine (correspond to `foreach` or a LINQ expression):

```
public async Task ConsumeSomeDataAsync(string sql)
{
    var hub = new ProducerConsumerHub<IDataRecord>();
    var producerTask = GetSomeDataAsync(sql, rdr => rdr, hub);

    while (true)
    {
        var nextItemTask = hub.ConsumeAsync();
        await Task.WhenAny(producerTask, nextItemTask);

        if (nextItemTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            // process the next data item
            Console.WriteLine(await nextItemTask);
        }

        if (producerTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            // process the end of sequence
            await producerTask;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Coroutine execution helper (can also be implemented as a pair of [custom awaiters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx)):

```
public class ProducerConsumerHub<T>
{
    TaskCompletionSource<Empty> _consumer = new TaskCompletionSource<Empty>();
    TaskCompletionSource<T> _producer = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    // TODO: make thread-safe
    public async Task ProduceAsync(T data)
    {
        _producer.SetResult(data);
        await _consumer.Task;
        _consumer = new TaskCompletionSource<Empty>();
    }

    public async Task<T> ConsumeAsync()
    {
        var data = await _producer.Task;
        _producer = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        _consumer.SetResult(Empty.Value);
        return data;
    }

    struct Empty { public static readonly Empty Value = default(Empty); }
}
```

This is just an idea. It might be an overkill for a simple task like this, and it could be improved in some areas (like thread-safety, race conditions and handling the end of the sequence without touching `producerTask`). Yet it illustrates how the asynchronous data retrieval and processing could possibly be decoupled.

Comment: Tnx. I don't udnerstand how `GetSomeDataAsync` is used with `ConsumeSomeDataAsync` . Both take sql command ??

Comment: @RoyiNamir, `ConsumeSomeDataAsync` calls `GetSomeDataAsync` to start the sequence and simply passes it the `sql` string.

Comment: Could I be able to do something like `ConsumeSomeDataAsync().Where(...)` ? ( currently not)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, here is a simple fiddle showing the concept: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8gQVt2. No, you won't be able to use standard LINQ.

Comment: Thank you . can I refer this as "async bursts of data" ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I'm not sure about the terminology :)

Comment: no middle buffers , pure async fetch  and spit out data as soon it is available.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I guess you could say so. Figuratively speaking, this a special case of producer/consumer pattern, with the queue size of 1 element and without blocking any threads. TPL Dataflow allows for much more complex scenarios. Then, there's also Rx.

Comment: should'nt `_conn.Open();` be `await _conn.OpenAsync();` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, yes that's what it should be, fixed. We don't want any blocking code. I did that for `rdr.Read()` but overlooked `_conn.Open` when copied your code. Note, I didn't test the SQL stuff. I only tested [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8gQVt2).

Comment: You need to pass in a cancellationtoken and check for it inside the while loop

Answer (score 1):

This [Medium article](https://medium.com/@sergiis/before-c-8-0-async-streams-come-out-d154f8a20ce9) describes another solution, which is to use the `Dasync/AsyncEnumerable` library.

The library is open source, available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable), and provides a readable syntax to use now, for `IAsyncEnumerable`, until [C# 8.0 comes out and provides its own implementation and language support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/) in the form of `async ... yield return` and `await foreach`.

(I have no connection with the library; I came across it as a possible very useful solution to - what I think is! - the same problem as yours, on a project I'm developing.)