# Can I await an enumerable I create with a generator?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, generator, promise

Let's say I have a sequence of integers I obtain asynchronously.

```
async Task<int> GetI(int i){
    return await Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(x => i);
}
```

I want to create a generator over that sequence, if the sequence was synchronous I'd do:

```
IEnumerable<int> Method()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        yield return GetI(i); // won't work, since getI returns a task
    }
}
```

So, I figured the analogy is making the generator async and yielding from it:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<int>> Method()    
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        yield return await Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(x => i);
    }
}
```

This won't work, since a method with `yield` must return an `IEnumerable` of something, the alternative, which makes more sense is `IEnumerable<Task<int>>` but that won't compile since `async` methods must return `Task`s or void.

Now, I realize I can simply remove the await and return an `IEnumerable<Task<int>>` but that won't help me since the iteration will keep asking for data before any of it is ready, so it doesn't solve my issue.

- Is there any way to nicely mix enumerables and tasks with the nice sugar the language gives me with await and yield?
- Is there any way to nicely consume it?

<sup>(From searching online, I suspect the answer to the first question is false and the second one is an observer/observable, but I couldn't find any canonical reference and I'm interested in the best way to implement this pattern in C#)</sup>

Comment: Are you actually trying to get a `Task<IEnumerable<int>>`, or an `IEnumerable<Task<int>>`? The latter is significantly easier to achieve... but it's not clear what you're actually trying to get out of this.

Comment: (I do understand that expressing what you're trying to achieve in this sort of situation can be very difficult, by the way.)

Comment: @JonSkeet On the off chance of sounding stupid, I _think_ I'm trying to get a `Task<IEnumerable<Task<int>>>`, I want to get an iterator that I'll wait for initially and then wait for at each iteration. However, an `IEnumerable<Task<int>>` is also acceptable, the problem is as I mention in the question is that the IEnumerable will get consumed synchronously on the consumer where I want to wait for it at every iteration before consuming the next element. I'm wondering if there is a clever way to do this that does not involve a regular for loop pausing the iteration by `await` there.

Comment: @JonSkeet  ( Honest full disclosure, I'm trying to formulate a better opinion on [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4PVbLpUIdzoMDR5dWstRllXblU/) after watching [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2014/Keynote-Duality) and I'm trying to figure how C# addresses that problem, I'd probably use an event emitter or something similar in C# normally))

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23854102/1768303) is closely related. AFAICT, what you're trying to do would be a great C# language + LINQ runtime feature, but it's just not available yet. Check also  Stephen Toub's ["Tasks, Monads, and LINQ"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/04/03/tasks-monads-and-linq.aspx).

Comment: What you're looking for is something like `IAsyncEnumerable` which exposes per-element asynchrony.

Comment: In 2016 perspective - I was thinking about async iterators - they now exist natively in Python and are being considered for JavaScript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Asynchronous sequences are interesting. There's a number of different approaches, depending on exactly what you want to do. I'm not entirely clear on your desired semantics, so these are some of the options.

`Task<IEnumerable<T>>` is an asynchronously-retrieved collection. There is only one task - one asynchronous operation - that retrieves the entire collection. This does not sound like it's what you want.

`IEnumerable<Task<T>>` is a (synchronous) sequence of (asynchronous) data. There are multiple tasks, which may or may not all be processing simultaneously. There are a couple of options for implementing this. One is using an enumerator block and yielding tasks; this approach will start a new asynchronous operation each time the next item is retrieved from the enumerable. Alternatively, you can create and return a collection of tasks with all tasks running concurrently (this can be done elegantly over a source sequence via LINQ's `Select` followed by `ToList`/`ToArray`). However, this has a couple of drawbacks: there is no way to asynchronously determine if the sequence is already ended, and it's not easy to immediately start the *next* item processing after returning the current item (which is commonly desired behavior).

The core problem is that `IEnumerable<T>` is inherently synchronous. There are a couple of workarounds. One is `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, which is an asynchronous equivalent of `IEnumerable<T>` and available in the [Ix-Async NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Async/). This approach has its own drawbacks, though. Of course, you lose the nice language support for `IEnumerable<T>` (namely, enumerator blocks and `foreach`). Also, the very notion of an "asynchronous enumerable" is not exactly performant; ideally, asynchronous APIs should be chunky rather than chatty, and enumerables are very chatty. More discussion on the [original design here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Rx-Update-Async-support-IAsyncEnumerable-and-more-with-Jeff-and-Wes), and on the [chunky/chatty considerations here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acdfd47f-4216-4797-9714-fb4fbeafb36c/is-iasyncenumerator-dead?forum=rx).

So, these days a much more common solution is to use [observables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) or [dataflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (both also available via NuGet). In these cases, you have to think of the "sequence" as something with a life of its own. Observables are push-based, so the consuming code is (ideally) reactive. Dataflows have an actor feel, so they act more independent, again pushing results to the consuming code.

Answer (score 3):

You could return an `IEnumerable<Task<int>>`:

```
IEnumerable<Task<int>> Method()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        yield return Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(x => i);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
foreach(var i in Method())
    Console.WriteLine(await i);
```

Comment: Note that a consumer doesn't need to wait for the task to be completed before asking for the next task, so if the generator isn't build to work properly when multiple items are requested in parallel it could be problematic.

Comment: what about using `await` in here? `await Task.Delay(1000)` above the `yield return`, would it cause current and all future iterations to be resolved only after an addtiaional 1000 milliseconds?