# Is there a conceptual type of promise that toggles states?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise, deferred

The common use of a promise/deferred implementation is to create a promise, then after some asynchronous event occurs, decide whether to resolve or reject the promise.

Of course, once a promise has been resolved or rejected, its state cannot be changed -- it has been fulfilled.

What I am wondering is if there is a concept sort of similar to promises, but a kind of scenario in which the state might go back and forth.

For example, say a particular service is available every 5 minutes for a period of 60 seconds.

Whenever the service is available, any requests are fulfilled (passed to it) immediately. Whenever the service is unavailable, requests are pending and added to a queue, and as soon as the service becomes available, all backed-up requests in the queue are sent and fulfilled.

I know this concept isn't a promise, but I was wondering if this is an actual named situation in programming, and if there are existing library implementations of it (particularly in Node.js).

Did that make sense? Does such a thing exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is *like* a promise but can resolve mutliple times?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29958779/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi maybe [*What is the inverse of a promise?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084439/what-is-the-inverse-of-a-promise)

Comment: Also, lol, the guy who asked the question is called "M Miller".

Comment: But yeah, in all seriousness - you probably want an observable.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Nah, my question about the inverse of a promise is asking for a thing that only changes it's state once only (that's why I haven't accepted your answer yet)

Comment: @Bergi That is exactly what I was looking for! Should've looked more closely at similar search results, I wasn't sure if I was explaining it right. Thanks!