# How to return async IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
public async IEnumerable<string> GetListDriversAsync()
{
   var drives = await graphClient.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
        foreach (var d in drives)
            yield return d.ToString(); 
}
```

But compiler error says:

> "The return type of an async must be void, Task or Task `<T>`"

How do I return IEnumerable when the method is async?

Comment: Rename your method signature to `public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetListDriversAsync()`

Comment: I tried this already, it says: "the body cannot be an iterator because Task<IEnumerable<string>> is not an interface type"

Comment: The short answer is that what you want to do cannot be done in the current version of C#. You can keep your iterator method if you encapsulate it in a local function, but you will need to fully populate a collection and return this to use the `async` keyword and the `Task<T>` return type. There is no support right now for "async yield return".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async Task<IEnumerable> with yield return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882078/async-taskienumerable-with-yield-return)

Comment: Both async/await and iterator methods involves compiler magic that rewrites your method, they cannot work together right now.

Comment: Is C# 8 Async enumerable allowed? https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/01/09/iasyncenumerable-in-c-8/

Comment: What you are trying to do is "async enumerables" - that's a vNext feature; right now: there aren't great options for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetListDriversAsync()
{
    var drives = await graphClient.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();

    IEnumerable<string> GetListDrivers()
    {
        foreach (var d in drives)
            yield return d.ToString();
    }

    return GetListDrivers();
}
```

Comment: Just for my own understanding - why the local function and `yield return` in this case instead of `return drives.Select(d => d.ToString())` ?

Comment: @ScottHannen see [Local functions and exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions#local-functions-and-exceptions) which discusses exception handling with enumerators in relation to local functions

Comment: @ScottHannen - The OP wanted `yield` so that's why I wrote it that way. Marathon55 is also rigth about it being the right pattern to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative way is possible in [C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/async-streams). It uses [IAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0).

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetListDriversAsync()
{
    var drives = await graphClient.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
    foreach (var d in drives)
        yield return d.ToString();
}
```

It will alter your signature a bit, which may (or may not) be an option for you.

Usage:

```
await foreach (var driver in foo.GetListDriversAsync())
{
    Console.WriteLine(driver );
}
```